# Error when running INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I'm trying to merge 2 identical mysql tables. One is called kpi_table and the other one stage_kpi_table. Both are aggregation tables but stage_kpi_table is a table that has the latest info that I'd need to add to kpi_table. This is a method that I'm using to make a daily update of my kpis.
The problem is that I'm getting the following error when running the update:
`SQL Error [1136] [21S01]: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`

I found many threads and read the documentation. However I don't see what I'm doing wrong.
I'm using pandas (in python 3.7) to_sql to create the tables

This is how I'm creating the table in python:
`kpi_df.to_sql('kpi_table', con=mysql_conn)`
This is the structure of both tables

```
CREATE TABLE `kpi_table` (
  `index` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `total_users` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `concurrent` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `new_users` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `_1dayActive` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`date`),
  KEY `ix_kpi_table_index` (`index`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

As you can see I set the 'date' field as my primary key
This is a sample of my data

```
Out[272]: 
        date  total_users  concurrent  new_users  _1dayActive
0 2019-06-12            5           2        5.0            5
1 2019-06-13            8           3        3.0            7
2 2019-06-14           13           3        5.0           10
3 2019-06-15           13           2        0.0            6
4 2019-06-16           13           2        0.0            6
...
```

And this is the query that gives the error (I'm testing this directly on mysql editor DBeaver:

```
INSERT INTO kpi_table (`date`, `total_users`, `concurrent`, `new_users`, `_1dayActive`) 
(SELECT * FROM stage_kpi_table as skpi)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE total_users = (skpi.total_users);
```

What I expect the kpi_table to be updated with the other table based on the 'date' field. If the date exists, update values ('total_users' for this example), otherwise insert a new row.

I'm sure it must be something silly but I haven't been able to figure out.
Many thanks!!
Raul.

Comment: Instead of doing `SELECT *`, you should `SELECT` the specific columns that you are inserting. Error message is quite clear; you are inserting into 5 columns; while `SELECT *` is returning 6 columns, so it is not able to map

Comment: number of columns not able to map in insert from select. to solve this error mention column name instead of * after select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO kpi_table ('date', 'total_users', 'concurrent', 'new_users', '_1dayActive')
(SELECT 'date', 'total_users', 'concurrent', 'new_users', '_1dayActive' FROM stage_kpi_table as skpi)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE total_users = (skpi.'total_users');
```

Comment: that was fast, many thanks! Wrong assumption on my side when thinking that since they were identical I didn't have to still list all the fields.
I got another error saying that it total_users was unkown so I had to add a little tweak to the code: ```INSERT INTO lobbySN.kpi_table (`date`, `total_users`, `concurrent`, `new_users`, `_1dayActive`)
(SELECT `date`, `total_users`, `concurrent`, `new_users`, `_1dayActive` FROM lobbySN.stage_kpi_table as skpi)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE total_users = VALUES(`total_users`);```

Comment: @raul Well, if you've included `index` field too then it would have worked with *. Yeap, you are right the fields are stored in your db with quotations.